# Groovy process output gets cuts - only prints the first line

Tags: curl, groovy

When I call curl from command line with:

```
curl -X POST -v -k -u admin:admin https://[my-host]
```

I get multiple lines of output (-v option):

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to my-host 443 (#0)
 *   Trying xxx.xx.xx.xx...
 * Connected to my-host (xxx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
 ...
 * Server auth using Basic with user '****'
  < HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

I am trying to do the same from groovy with this code:

```
  public void post() {
    def command = "curl -X POST -v -k -u admin:admin https://[my-host]"
    String result = executeOnShell(command, new File("."))
    println result
  }


  private String executeOnShell(String command, File workingDir) {
    def result = ""
    def process = new ProcessBuilder(addShellPrefix(command))
        .directory(workingDir)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start()
    process.inputStream.eachLine {
      // Trying to concat the output 
      result += it + "\n"

    }
    process.waitFor();
    return result
  }

  private def addShellPrefix(String command) {
    def commandArray = new String[3]
    commandArray[0] = "sh"
    commandArray[1] = "-c"
    commandArray[2] = command
    return commandArray
  }
```

but when I run that code I only get one line of output:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
```

How do I capture all the output/lines in the `result` variable above?

Comment: Have you tried `-o -` as curl param?

Comment: I would rather be able to print to console instead of -o as a workaround to write to a file instead.

Comment: `-o -` writes it to stdout

Comment: I also tried that, same result. Its not that nothing gets written to console, the problem is that for some reason its only the first line that is captured in the above groovy code.

Comment: Put println to print result before return statement, verify that all content is getting printed in executeOnShell().

Comment: try to use http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#waitForProcessOutput(java.lang.Appendable,%20java.lang.Appendable) instead of `process.inputStream.eachLine` and `process.waitFor`

Comment: hm could you be a bit more specific/provide an example? Not sure what you suggest I should chose from from that link